# How do I echo an line from a text file which has title or meta tags?

Tags: php

I have a text file which looks like the following:

```
 http://tisue.net/jandek/live.html
<title>Jandek: Live</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2004/06/0629_040629_camelspider.html
<title>Camel Spiders: Behind an E-Mail Sensation From Iraq</title>
<meta name="description" content="A photo of a U.S. soldier in Iraq holding massive,   hairy, supposedly flesh-eating spiders has been burning up e-mail in-boxes around the  world. The arachnids (called camel spiders or wind scorpions) are real, but scientists say many claims about them are anything but.">
```

and several thousand more like that.

I'm using `fopen()` and `fgets()` to read each line and echo it. The problem is that the `<title>` and `<meta />` are not being echoed; the lines return blank. How can I get php to see these as plain text and echo them?

EDIT: Here's the code I'm using:

```
 $handle = fopen($myFile, 'r');

 while(!feof($handle)){

   $data = fgets($handle);
   echo $data;
```

Comment: Added the code to the question, thanks.

Comment: That code should work fine. Are you checking with a browser?

Comment: Yes. The lines which have title or meta tags come out blank.

Comment: Try using `file_get_contents()` instead to grab the contents?

Comment: You have to apply htmlspecialchars() on your echo.

Comment: @NicholasPickering I'm dealing with huge files (100 MB/ hundreds of thousands of records), so I think that will be too slow.

Comment: @Jack that worked perfectly, thank you! Please add it as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: It's already part of an existing answer by now :)

Comment: True, but I think you should get the credit.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to view the source code of the page to see the `<title>` and `<meta>` tags. This can be achieved by right clicking the page and clicking `view-source` in most browsers.

Alternatively you could convert the tags so they're readable in html by using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
$handle = fopen($myFile, 'r');

while(!feof($handle)){

    $data = fgets($handle);
    echo htmlspecialchars($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to check weather the page have meta tags which you want exits. 
It can be done with get_meta_tags() , more info here http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php

And for reading each line use file() to read it line by line.

```
<?php
$lines = file("fileurl");
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    echo($line);
}
?>
```